# mysqli affected_rows returns -1

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm doing this very simple query in PHP. It runs fine when I execute it on PhpMyAdmin separately, but in the code, `affected_rows` is returning -1, indicating an error. I'm not sure what might be wrong . . .

```
    //connect to database
    $conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

    if($conn->connect_error) {
        hrms_error("Error: Can't connect to database.");
    }

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM employee WHERE emp_id = 'BBPL/E0016' 
                             AND is_active = '1'");

    $result = $query->execute();

    if ($result == false) {
        hrms_error("Query failed.");
    }

    $num_rows = $query->affected_rows;
    echo $num_rows;
```

Comment: So naturally you looked up `affected_rows` in the documentation to discover what this result means, and you found....?

Comment: I take it you have a custom `hrms_error()` function?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That -1 means there was an error in query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it's nothing but something that produces JavaScript so that error messages can be shown as `alert()`.

Comment: @dotslash: That could have been replaced with a simple `die` to make this a self-contained testcase.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually I wanted to produce a JavaScript `alert()` and then redirect the page (this is how I want it to behave). Anyway, the problem is solved now; thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: @dotslash: It doesn't matter how you want it to behave. You should post self-contained testcases. This JavaScript `alert` has nothing to do with the problem so you should have abstracted it away. I can't stress how important it is to post self-contained testcases without unnecessary external blurb.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay, will keep that in mind from now on! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong function. Replace $query->affected_rows; with $query->num_rows

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot. :) PHP can be so damn confusing at times. :P
I'll accept your answer as soon as the site allows me to.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted so the question will not remain open.

Comment: Actually the question should be closed as it is effectively just a typo and will not help others.

Comment: I don't see it as a typo. he selected the wrong function and did not get the results he expected. What am I missing?